# ¿Cómo comparar lo que tengo dentro de un tag html con una variable usando javascript?

Tags: javascript

Por ejemplo tengo `<li>Javascript</li>` y `const lenguaje = 'Javascript'` necesito saber si lo que esta adentro de `li` osea `'Javascript'` es igual a lo que esta guardado en `lenguaje`. Intenté hacerlo con este código pero no funciono:

```
if (document.querySelector('li').innerText === lenguaje) {
            document.querySelector('li').remove();
}
```

Comment: ¿Intentaste ocupando `==` en vez de `===`?

Comment: Si se tiene un <li> antes antes del <li>javascript</li> podría ser ese el problema, ya que querySelector('li') retorna el primer li que encuentra

Comment: Ese era el problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes proceder de este modo:

- Usa `querySelectorAll()` para recuperar una lista de nodos en lugar de solo `querySelector` que solo te retornaría uno
- Lo anterior por que puedes tener mas de un elemento de lista desordenada
- Puedes identificar mediante id o clases o directamente por la precedencia de las tags, de este modo: `ul > li`
- El orden anterior para que de esta forma indicamos que recupere todas las etiquetas li que son hijas de ul
- Como lo propuesto devuelve un nodo, entonces puedes iterar o simplemente indicar la posición en la que se encuentra
- Usa de preferencia `===` para comparar de modo estricto

Código

```html
    <ul>
      <li>JavaScript</li>
      <li>PHP</li>
    </ul>
    
    <script>
      let listado = document.querySelectorAll("ul > li")
      let cadena = "JavaScript"
      let resultado = listado[0].textContent
      console.log(resultado === cadena)
    </script>
```

Iterando todos los nodos recuperados

```html
    <ul>
      <li>JavaScript</li>
      <li>PHP</li>
    </ul>
    
    <script>
      let listado = document.querySelectorAll("ul > li")
      let cadena = "JavaScript"
      for (elemento of listado) {
        (cadena === elemento.textContent) ? (console.log("Existe aquí")) : (console.log("No existe aquí"))
      }
    </script>
```